How to clear the display at startup
I am using RPI 3B+ Bullseye Lite without X as a video player contolled over SSH. I had preferred to start with a blank screen.
Writing the following in /etc/rc.local
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -foreground black -background black -clear all >/dev/tty0"

has no effect.
But if i run the same from command line after startup, the display is cleared. Can anybody tell me why, and how can the display be cleared at startup?

Why sudo? Why a new shell? What is wrong with clear?

your question is not Raspberry Pi specific ... it is a Linux question

@Milliways  clear in rc.local will not clear the display connected to RPI.

Forget rc.local which has been obsolete for 10 years. Use ANY of the methods that work with systemd.
